# Automatically replace a word with hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is there any way to automatically replace every word with a hyperlink. See, I have certan repeated words which needs to get attested with a hyperlink. In the given example, I require `Ronaldo` (Only For the First Appearance) to get linked with following link. I tried this way which didn't work.

```
<p>
Ronaldo; born 5 February 1985 is a Portuguese professional footballer who plays as a forward for Serie A club Juventus and captains the Portugal national team. Often considered the best player in the world and widely regarded as one of the greatest players of all time. Ronaldo has won five Ballons d'Or and four European Golden Shoes. Ronaldo is one of the few recorded players to have made over 1,000 professional career appearances and has scored over 700 senior career goals for club and country. Ronaldo is also the second player to score 100 international goals, and the first European to achieve the feat.
</p>

<script>
var Ronaldo = document.search("Ronaldo");
Ronaldo.replace("Ronaldo","<a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristiano_Ronaldo'>Ronaldo</a>")
</script>
```

Comment: You need to search for the word in the `innerhtml` of a tag.

Comment: Take a look at jQuery's [wrap](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/#wrap-wrappingElement). But where is the data for the links stored? It's no use to store it into the same html file within a script, as you could hardcode the links to the markup as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('Ronaldo', '<a href="ronaldo link">Ronaldo</a>
```

Using replace without global regular expression will only replace the first appearance.

Comment: Yeah, That's what i wanted. Using `replaceAll` would be messy for me.